# Why won't mysql workbench allow me to execute or create a schema?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanna create a schema because I wanna test out tables. I tried to click the "create a new schema", button at the top but it was glazed over where if I click it, nothing happens as if it isn't even there. So after this, I thought "Well I'll try and execute a schema via a statement until then I realized that the execute button is also glazed over. I'm wondering if there's something wrong and obvious I did since I just installed MySQL and have done nothing else in the settings.

[image: https://gyazo.com/0e445104c548f1084e9912bfce4b35c8]

Comment: Is this the image? https://i.gyazo.com/0e445104c548f1084e9912bfce4b35c8.png

Comment: Yes. I don't know what to do here i tried looking up videos and did the exact same thing in the two i watched but when i do it its glazed over

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Can you explain more? 
[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: okay sorry i'll explain better. I wanna create a schema because i wanna test out tables. I tried to click the "create a new schema", button at the top but it was glazed over where if i click it, nothing happens as if it isn't even there. So after this i thought "Well i'll try and execute a schema via a statement', until then i realized that the execute button is also glazed over. I'm wondering if there's something wrong and obvious i did since i just installed mysql and have done nothing else in the settings.

Comment: This may help: https://youtu.be/WuBcTJnIuzo

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click and create the schema from MySQLWorkbench. The steps are below:

**List of Schemas in UI**

[image: Schemas in UI]

**Right-click, and select *Create Schema***

[image: Right click]

**Specify the name of the schema to be created**

[image: Specify schema]

**Click *Apply*, confirm the SQL script in the dialog box, and again click *Apply***

[image: Confirm schema]

**Note the successful execution of the script**

[image: Execution]

**Verify the new schema in the Schemas section in UI**

[image: Verification]